# Visualizing the set of points in a regular polygon closer to center than to vrtices (Voronoi cell)?

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, python

Let $P_n$ be the regular convex $n$-gon centered at $p_0$ with $n$ vertices $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ and $(n>2)$.

Let $S_n$ be the set of all points "$s$" within the region bounded by $P_n$ where:

$distance(s,p_0) \leq distance(s,p_k)$...   $(\forall k=\{1,2,...,n\})$.

For instance $S_3$ would look like this:

[image]

And $S_4$ would look like this:

[image]

And just thinking about this to the extreme... $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ should look something like this (call it "$S_\infty$" for simplicity):

[image]

> > Is there a way to show (either using geometry or a simple brute-force code in Python) what $S_n$ should look like for any $n>2$?

I would really like to see what shapes emerge. Is there a way to animate it in Python? Like have circles radiate from each vertex $p_k$ and the center $p_0$ until they crash into each other to make straight lines defining the new region $S_n$?

Depending on the answer, I'd ideally like to transpose this question into 3-D for the 5 platonic solids.

For instance, examining a cube (i.e. 8 vertices), define $D_8$ as the set of all points "$s$" such that:

$distance(s,p_0) \leq distance(s,p_k)$...   $(\forall k=\{1,2,...,8\})$.

Then $D_8$ is actually a truncated octahedron! I'm super curious what the other 4 platonic solids produce... As well as what higher $S_n$ regions look like (e.g. for a pentagon, hexagon, octagon, dodecagon, etc.).

> > Here's an insight that I find to be an elegant solution for n=3,4, or 6 (triangle, square, hexagon). Observe that you can tessellate all of 2-D space with regular triangles, squares, and regular hexagons. Now imagine each vertex $p_k$ is actually the center of a nearby triangle/square/hexagon (centered at $p_k$ instead of at $p_0$).

For instance: $S_3$ can be more easily distinguished by drawing 3 more triangles centered at $p_1, p_2 and p_3$.

[image]

Similarly for $S_4$, drawing 4 more squares centered at $p_1, p_2, p_3 and p_4$ would show us the shape below, which we can then easily discern needs to be distilled into the $S_4$ shading we saw above.

[image]

> > **EDIT:**

Based on the comment about Voronoi Diagrams, I did more research and tried it out in R. Here's the region $S_8$ for example (use your imagination to connect the 8 outer dots to form the enclosing octagon):
[image]

The upshot seems to be that actually only $n=3$ and $n=4$ were interesting. For $n>4$ the pattern is simply to create a smaller version of the n-gon rotated by the internal angle of that n-gon. The shrinkage continues forever, but is also slowing forever, with the limit being circle of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ shown in the $S_\infty$ diagram from above.

More directly:

$\dfrac{Area(S_3)}{Area(P_3)}=\dfrac{2}{3}$

$\dfrac{Area(S_4)}{Area(P_4)}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\dots = \dots$

$\dfrac{Area(S_\infty)}{Area(P_\infty)}=\dfrac{1}{4}$ (limit -> lower bound)

Comment: You're talking about the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the vertices and the centroid.

Comment: Geometrically, that inequality represents the half-space containing $p_0$ defined by the perpendicular bisecting plane of the line segment connecting $p_0$ and $p_k$. Take the intersection of all these half-spaces with the original polyhedron.

Comment: @mr_e_man As said in a compact way by Rahul, it is the Voronoi cell associated with the center $p_0$, in the Voronoi diagram generated by the $p_k$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain it easily with Wolfram Mathematica (see the pictures below).

> P[n_] := Table[{Cos[2*Pi*i/n], Sin[2*Pi*i/n]}, {i, 0, n}];
>
> graph[n_] := RegionPlot[AllTrue[Table[(x - P[n][[i, 1]])^2 + (y -
>   P[n][[i, 2]])^2, {i, 1,n}], # > x^2 + y^2 &], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
>   PlotPoints -> 20];

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The 3D version can be built in the same way. For instance, for the tetrahedron:

> P = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}};
>
> p2 = ConvexHullMesh[P, 
>      MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Thick, Black}, 2 -> Opacity[0.2]}];
>
> p1 = RegionPlot3D[
>      RegionMember[p2, {x, y, z}] && AllTrue[
>        Table[
>         Norm[{x, y, z} - P[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[P]}], # > 
>          x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &]
>      , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 60];
>
> Show[p2, p1, ViewPoint -> {2, 4, 4}]

[image]

Comment: It's neat that for the cube some of the faces are perfect hexagons.

Comment: @PierreCarre can you please provide the sample code for the cube? I'm not too familiar with these functions in mathematica unfortunately

Comment: @Andrew I just added some code for the 3D case.